# Automated git pull on Windows 8 as system

Tags: windows, windows-8, git, scheduled-tasks, msysgit

I have installed [msysgit](https://code.google.com/p/msysgit/) for windows 8.  I am attempting to automate a git pull every 5 minutes.  I am using scheduled tasks to run a script I wrote. The schedule task's action is:

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass File C:\Path\To\Git\Script.ps1
```

The script file mentioned above contains:

```
cd C:/Path/To/Git/Repository
git pull
```

When I run this script as a local user, it works successfully.  However when I switch it to run as system, it appears to run successfully but it does not.  The scheduled task runs successfully but the repository does not pull in new code.

Does anyone have any suggestions for running this task silently and successfully in the background?

Comment: Why do you want to give `SYSTEM` privileges to third-party software that certainly doesn't need them?

Comment: Try it running as you, but check the "Hidden" checkbox.

Comment: @grawity not ideal but ssh key tied to that computer only has read access to the git repo

Comment: @MarkAllen It works if I run it as the local user, but the "hidden" checkbox does not hide the window.  The hidden checkbox doesn't seem to change it at all.

Comment: Weird. Well, make a new user account, configure it to run as that user, even when not logged on (which should be an option.). Then log off and back on as yourself.

Comment: @MarkAllen I think this should be a viable option.  I'll update once I give that a try.  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

because youre not authenticated as the github user on the system account

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).